# What is the 6 in DATETIME(6) in MySQL mean?

Tags: mysql

I can't find it in the [DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) but I usually define it as `DATETIME` with no precision specifier.

I noticed this when Hibernate automatic DDL update is run it alters the table to `DATETIME(6)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is documented on [the page *before*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-type-syntax.html) the actual page you linked to in the ToC (emphasis mine):

> MySQL permits **fractional seconds** for `TIME`, `DATETIME`, and `TIMESTAMP` values, **with up to microseconds (6 digits) precision**. To define a column that includes a fractional seconds part, use the syntax `type_name(fsp)`, where `type_name` is `TIME`, `DATETIME`, or `TIMESTAMP`, and `fsp` is the fractional seconds precision.
>
> [...]
>
> The `fsp` value, if given, must be in the range 0 to 6. A value of 0 signifies that there is no fractional part. **If omitted, the default precision is 0**. (This differs from the standard SQL default of 6, for compatibility with previous MySQL versions.)

- So `DATETIME` is equivalent to `DATETIME(0)`.
- And `DATETIME(6)` **is not** equivalent to `DATETIME` nor `DATETIME(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

It indicates the precision to which the milliseconds is stored.
DATETIME(6) means that the fractional milliseconds is stored upto 6 decimal places. For example, 1970-01-01 17:51:04.789463.
The number must range between 0 and 6.

Comment: 6 digits = **micro**second